# How to use 'OR' with Mocha / Chai

Tags: testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to test if a text has text1 OR text2. Something like:

```
expect(text).to.contain.text1 || expect(text).to.contain.text2.
```

- There is not `.or`
- any doesn't work because `.text()` doesn't allow me to do:

  `expect(text).to.contain.any.text(text1,text2)`
- No, this doesn't work: `expect(text).to.contain.text1 || expect(text).to.contain.text2`.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `.oneOf(list)` or `.satisfy(function)`.

For example,

```
expect(text).to.be.oneOf(['hello', 'world']);
```

Or

```
expect(text).to.satisfy(function (t) {
  return t === 'hello' || t === 'world';
});
```

Comment: Thank you ntalbs.  Satisfy did the job perfectly.  Thank you very much!  Here the links:  1) [oneOf](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_oneof)  2) [satisfy](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_satisfy)